# Visualização de XSD

Tags: xml, código-aberto, xsd, diagrama

Em nossa vida de desenvolvimento nós sempre nos deparamos com vários desafios. Sempre que precisei visualizar um XSD na forma de um diagrama, utilizei-me do programa [XSD Diagram](http://regis.cosnier.free.fr/?page=XSDDiagram), veja a imagem abaixo:
[image: XSD Diagram mostrando um diagrama de um arquivo XSD]

Contudo, de uns dias pra cá o software tem me deixado na mão, pois fica travado quando abro os mesmos arquivos que sempre abri. Já testei em outra máquina também obteve o mesmo comportamento.

### A pergunta

Conhecem algum software que fala a visualização de arquivos XSD compostos, de maneira similar a esse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu gosto do [Altova XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html).

Outra opção seria o [Liquid XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Xml-Schema-Editor.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Opção que mais gostei, com visualização de três tipos: text plain, arvóre e diagrama, com opção de gerar documentação automaticamente: WMHelp XMLPad.